# If the product of a $k$ form with any $n-k$ form vanishes, then the form is $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $V$ be a real vector space of dimension $n$. Is it true that if for some $\tau \in \Lambda^k(V^*)$, $k<n$, we have that $\tau \wedge \omega = 0$ for every $\omega \in \Lambda^{n-k}(V^*)$, then $\tau = 0$?

This is motivated by trying to prove that the Hodge star operator is a point operator: let $g$ be a Riemannian metric on an manifold giving rise to a volume form $dv$. On $k$-forms we define $*$ by $\omega \wedge *\tau = g(\omega, \tau)dv$. I'm trying to see that this is a point operator. Supposing at some $x \in M$, $\tau_x = 0$, we have that $g_x(\omega, \tau) = 0$, since $g$ is a tensor, so a point operator. Hence reducing to $V = T_xM$, $\dim V=n$, what I'm trying to prove reduces to the claim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true. An inner product on $V$ induces an inner product on $\wedge^k V^*$ via the Hodge star operator, namely
$$\langle\eta_1,\eta_1\rangle:=\eta_1\wedge\star\eta_2\in\wedge^n V^*\cong\mathbb{R}$$
Then, taking $\tau=\eta_1$ and $\eta_2=\omega=\star\tau$, you obtain the result, since
$$\langle\tau,\omega\rangle=\tau\wedge\star\tau=||\tau||^2=0\iff\tau=0$$